# When a volume decreases in a real gas, what is more likely: temperature decrease or pressure increase?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

The ideal gas law states that when the volume is lowered, either the temperature drops or the pressure rise.

Under real-life situations, how does nature "decides" what to increase or decrease in value? Why would the temperature drop instead of the pressure increase and vice-versa?

Suppose a submarine from OceanGate is diving in deep seas, and it implodes. What would happen to the air inside it when compressed by the water (thereby lowering the volume)?

1. Would its temperature decrease while its pressure stays constant?
2. Would its temperature stay constant while its pressure increases?
3. Would its temperature decrease a little while its pressure increases a little?

Out of these 3 options, what would happen? Or is my reasoning wrong and the temperature would increase for some reason? What is the temperature of the gas inside the submarine after imploding?

I'm extremely confused because I expected the temperature and pressure to rise like when a piston decreases the volume of its chamber in an engine, but that is not what the ideal gas law tells me.

Comment: I think this question will be closed for "lack of focus". I suggest that you concentrate on one question instead of asking several questions.

Comment: The question seems focused to me: With three variables in the ideal gas law, how do we know how one of them (the temperature) changes as the other two (pressure, volume) change? This is the focus of my answer below.

Comment: This question was closed after being answered. I don't understand the pettiness. I'm satisfied with the answer, but I keep thinking "Imagine if they just closed my question and the person that gave a proper answer never had the chance to do so". SE, like its big brother Stack Overflow, is really only about egoistic moderators applying the rules to please their thirst for censoring questions. THAT IS NOT MODERATION! It is said that the question is "unfocused" by the moderation, but apparently, it is focused enough to be answered properly and fully and to have 5 upvotes. PETTINESS, PETTINESS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The ideal gas law states that when the volume is lowered, either the temperature drops or the pressure rise.

It does not say this. It says only that $PV=nRT$; for instance, the pressure and temperature could both rise as the volume drops.

> Under real-life situations, how does nature "decides" what to increase or decrease in value? Why would the temperature drop instead of the pressure increase and vice-versa?

Nature seeks to increase the total entropy as rapidly as possible, subject to existing constraints.

What  this means is that we see the dominant [intensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) gradient—or spatial difference—even out, through energy transfer in the form of shifting of the [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) extensive property. The suppression of gradients in this way generates entropy.

As an example, a pair of objects has the highest entropy when both are at the same temperature, as opposed to one being hot and the other cold. Thus, we predict that in the absence of any other effect, temperatures spontaneously equilibrate when things are placed in thermal contact.

In the case of pressure vessel implosion, the dominant gradient can be considered the pressure difference, and we can expect volumes to shift to eliminate this difference. (Pressure is an intensive property, and volume is its conjugate extensive property.) In this case, water ingress compresses the air. This does work on the air, as the moving boundary gives each colliding air molecule a little momentum kick. The resulting internal energy increase of the air produces a temperature increase.

If compression occurs fast enough that there's no time for heat to flow between the water or air (certainly the case in this example), we can model the process as [adiabatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process), giving us the relation

$$\frac{T_\text{end}}{T_\text{start}}=\left(\frac{P_\text{end}}{P_\text{start}}\right)^{\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}},$$

where the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) $\gamma$ is 1.4 for air. This equation provides new information and answers your question of how Nature elects to change the temperature during the compression process. The equation supplements the constitutive gas law (e.g., $PV=nRT$), which can now be applied with the additional knowledge that the pressure and temperature are increasing as the volume decreases.

Compression stops when the water and air pressures are equal.

Now we have a new gradient, a thermal one: The water and heated air are at different temperatures. Conductive heat transfer at the boundary cools the air until it matches the water temperature.

But we're not done here. A density gradient between water and air causes the latter to rise. Further, a [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential) difference at the bubble interface humidifies the air and dissolves some of it into the water. Ignoring weather, ultimate equilibrium would correspond to a humidified atmosphere of air above aerated water, all at the same temperature.

Again, all of these processes occur under the principle of maximizing the total entropy, through eliminating any existing gradients as fast as the kinetics of the system (e.g., involving the material properties) allow.

Comment: Can we assume that the water pressure (since it is the whole ocean) doesn't really change?

Comment: That's a pretty safe assumption. The water temperature can also be taken as constant.

Comment: I like to present the following application of the gas law in such contexts: If you use a chimney fire to heat up a room from freezing cold to comfy, "how" does that happen? V of the room does not change, nor does p (or else doors could not be operated). In other words, the only "strategy" left for the fire to increase T is to decrease n! -- Of course, this completely ignores cause and effect! As elaborated in the above answer, the gas law by itself does not completely determine the outcome of processes.

Comment: That interesting outcome is the topic of Emden’s “[Why do we have winter heating?](https://www.nature.com/articles/141908a0)” and Kreuzer and Payne’s “[Thermodynamics of heating a room](http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/~pikovsky/teaching/stud_seminar/Heating_room.pdf)”.